# Ubuntu 14.04 CVE patching status

Tags: 14.04, security

I tried PCI scan on one of the 14.04 server box. It failed because of many CVE failures. I was trying my best to figure out the status of many CVEs the scan raised. Some of the CVEs I believe are fixed, for others I can not figure out the status - whether it's false alarm or it's fixed or won't be fixed. Server is up to date with all service packs. All CVEs are openssh related.

- CVE-2015-6564 - seems to be fixed in version 1.6.9p1-1, but latest available is 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8
- CVE-2016-10009, CVE-2016-10011,CVE-2016-10012 - Can't find any help at all

For example https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-10012.html says needed, but can't find what the resolution is.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Given that it is not marked as 'Fixed' yet in the older releases, that probably means it's not yet been patched by the Security team and released into the repositories.  Consider that some CVEs are more or less irrelevant, in the long run; a PCI scan is not necessarily trying to *exploit* a CVE but is basing things on version numbers (this is how most vulnerability scanners work), and they don't usually have accurate representations of whether things are manually patched or not.  (That's why security people like myself manually review reported vulnerabilities and whether a server is patched.)

Comment: ALso regarding the 2015 CVE, have you looked at the "released" line for Trusty and seen that they specify the version of the package which has the patch in the repositories, `1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.2`?